# Tap and go NFC card to Phone

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, samsung-galaxy

My apartment complex uses a generic card entry gate system.  I know my phone can read the card. Can my phone write the card so I can just carry my phone instead of the card? GALAXY S9+ Android 9.

NXP MIFARE Classic 1k
NfcA, MifareClassic, NdefFormatable

Comment: Have you [identified the type of NFC chip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13083339/295004) used by the entry card?